# 複素数の計算 (a+jb+c+jd; a,b,c,d:real) の出力型式の設定方法

Tags: python, python3

複素数の計算 (a+jb+c+jd; a,b,c,d:real) の出力が `1.23-0j` となります。
`1.23` と出力する方法を教えてください。 # 配列ではありません。

Comment: complex class の `repr()` を再定義するか、`z = a+jb+c+jd; z.real if z.imag == 0 else z` とするなど。

Comment: metropolisさん、早速の回答ありがとうございます。python初心者のため、repr()を再定義の意味が理解できません。
具体例をいただけると幸いです。
また、z = a+jb+c+jd ; z.real if z.imag == 0 else zは試してみましたが、結果に変化はなく、
(-0.8465066445094404-0j)のように出力されてしまいます。
以下、補足です。
f(x)= a4*x**4 + a3*x**3 + a2*x**2 + a1*x + a0 
g(x)= b4*x**4 + b3*x**3 + b2*x**2 + b1*x + b0 
ここで、a0～a4, b0～b4：実数、x：純虚数
としたとき、任意のxに対して、h=log10(abs(f/g)) を計算させようとしています。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すみません。原因は不明ですがz.real でうまくいきました。

Answer (score 0):

complex class の `repr()` を再定義するか、`z = a+jb+c+jd; z.real if z.imag == 0 else z` とするなど。

```
z = 1.23-0j
#虚数部が0の場合は実数部のみ表示
print(z.real if z.imag == 0 else z)
```

---

<sup>この投稿は @metropolis さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35683/#comment35465_35683)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>